# Cannot composer install with Symfony in PhpStorm

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, phpstorm, php-5.3

I have a problem with PhpStorm. I had trouble adding the Composer and Symfony commands to PhpStorm.

I receive a message of this style:

> Problem Failed to parse output as xml: Error on line 2: Content is not
> allowed in prolog.. Command php /root/Downloads/composer.phar list
> --format=xml Output Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in
> phar:///root/Downloads/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Descriptor/XmlDescriptor.php:90
> Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 phar:///root/Downloads/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Descriptor/XmlDescriptor.php(166):
>
> Symfony\Component\Console\Descriptor\XmlDescriptor->getApplicationDocument(Object(Composer\Console\Application),
> NULL)
>
> ## 1 phar:///root/Downloads/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Descriptor/Descriptor.php(55):
>
> Symfony\Component\Console\Descriptor\XmlDescriptor->describeApplication(Object(Composer\Console\Application),
> Array)
>
> ## 2 phar:///root/Downloads/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/DescriptorHelper.php(69):
>
> Symfony\Component\Console\Descriptor\Descriptor->describe(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput),
> Object(Composer\Console\Application), Array)
>
> ## 3 phar:///root/Downloads/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Command/ListCommand.php(81):
>
> Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\DescriptorHelper->describe(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Ou
> in
> phar:///root/Downloads/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Descriptor/XmlDescriptor.php
> on line 90

Can you help me find the solution please ?

Comment: oh.. my. you have  to use english

Comment: I have a problem with phpstorm. I had trouble adding the composer and symfony commands to PhpStorm.

I receive this message  :   
    Problem Failed to parse output as xml: Error on line 2: Content is not allowed in prolog.. Command php /root/Downloads/composer.phar list --format=xml Output Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in phar
  can you help me ?

Comment: edit your question

Comment: how you tried ?

Comment: PHP and IDE versions? Maybe your PHP is too old ( I see `php-5.3` tag)?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, is php-xml installed? (`php -i | grep libxml`) If it isn't, try installing that then trying this again.

Answer (score 0):

The version of PHP needs to be recent. On macOS by default you may end up with PHP 5.6, and PHPStorm actually choose /usr/bin/php as it's preferred option for commands.